# Promise cause to stackoverflow with infinity while loop

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to understand why I am getting stackoverflow error following this code:

```
const promise = new Promise((res,rej) => {
    res(4);
})

while(true){
    promise.then((v) => v)
}
```

I am expecting to get

```
4
4
4
4
.
.
.
```

but get:

```
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: `while(true)` is infinite loop and you are not logging/printing your resolve (4) anywhere so the first thing what you get is memory error.

Comment: `promise.then((v) => v)` adds a handler for when the promise resolves. So, you add an infinite amount of them (well, until the application crashes). You never log the result. Nor does the infinite loop allow for the promise to ever resolve.

Comment: promise.then((v) => console.log(v))` will achieve the same error

Comment: @DavidZaltsman that's because your loop is synchronous, while your promise is not. The promise function never gets a chance to run while your syncronous loop is going

Comment: Yes, because you're still *adding infinite amount of handlers*. And they never execute because *the infinite loop doesn't let the promise ever resolve*.

Comment: how can i fix that?

Comment: Delete the code and do `while(true) console.log(4);`  that's the current fix. If you want something else to happen then please explain what you're trying to do that's not 1. an out of memory exception 2. an infinite log of `4`s

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop inside of an async function like this as suggested below

```
async function someFunction(){
    while(true) {
        console.log(await promise);
    }
}
someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to illustrate how you might create an infinite series of promises that doesn't have this problem, but warning: your tab will get stuck:

```js
const pr = new Promise((res,rej) => {
    res(4);
});

(async () => {
  let promiseList = [];
  while(true){
    const p = pr.then((v) => console.log(v));
    promiseList.push(p);
    if (promiseList.length >= 20) {
       await Promise.all(promiseList);
       promiseList = [];
    }
  }
})();
```

Check your console and you'll see the 4s.